# PSP 1000 Internet Connectivity Problem

Tags: psp

I have a PSP 1000, and I have entered the necessary information into the network connection information, but the PSP keeps telling me that "A connection to the access point could not be established." My house uses a 'Arris Arris TG862G-CT TG862GTelephony Wireless Docsis 3.0 Cable Modem Router Gateway Xfinity Comcast' I think. Is there a way to get my PSP to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to connect your PSP is to setup your wireless network as Wireless-B only with WEP or WPA security (not WPA2 -- VERY INSECURE AT THIS POINT!).

The PSP hardware physically doesn't support modern Wifi/security protocols.